# How can I infer schema from a pub/sub input message

Tags: json, dictionary, google-bigquery, schema

How can I infer schema from an input that has been parsed as a python dictionary so that that schema can be used as an input for a bigquery schema. I wanted a class that can do that for me but wasn't able to achieve that.

Comment: Have you tried using Dataflow template for [Pub/Sub Topic to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/create-streaming-pipeline-template)? If this doesn't help, provide the input message and sample code which you have tried?

Comment: I've tried that but I'm currently making my own template (flex template), in that I have a different use case, so it doesn't works here, and the function used in the source code (dynamicDestinations) that outputs the schema uses is currently available only on the Java SDK

Comment: Could you provide the details asked above?